# Increase size of plotly pie chart in python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, figure

How can i increase the size of the below pie chart? It seems small size is due to the scale but i'm note sure.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=df['index'], values=df['label'])])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like something really easy to look up. https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below code before `fig.show()` and change the value of `width` or `height` as you wish for.

```py
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500
)
```